# Cache@2 with poetry in Azure DevOps Pipeline issues

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, python-poetry

I'm trying to run the following azure-pipelines.yml file in a managed build agent.

```yaml
    - task: UsePythonVersion@0
      inputs:
        versionSpec: $(pythonVersion)
      displayName: 'Use Python 3.10.8'

    - script: |
        export POETRY_VERSION=$(poetryVersion)
        curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python -
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=PATH]${PATH}:$HOME/.local/bin"
      displayName: 'Install poetry'

    - ${{ if eq(parameters.usePoetryCache, true) }}:
      - task: Cache@2
        inputs:
          key: 'poetry | "$(Agent.OS)" | poetry.lock'
          # restoreKeys: |
          #   poetry | "$(Agent.OS)"
          #   poetry
          path: $(venv)
          cacheHitVar: POETRY_CAHCE_RESTORED

    - script: |
          poetry config virtualenvs.in-project true
          poetry config virtualenvs.path $(venv)
      displayName: Configure Poetry

    - script: |
        poetry install
      displayName: Install dependencies
      condition: eq(variables.POETRY_CAHCE_RESTORED, 'false')

    - script: |
        poetry show coverage
      displayName: Check coverage installation

    - script: |
        poetry run coverage run -m pytest && poetry run coverage xml -o ${{ parameters.workingDirectory }}/${{ parameters.testResultsDir }}/coverage.xml
      displayName: Run tests & code coverage # THIS FAILS
```

I don't understand why the caching step succeeds but `poetry run` fails. **This only happens if the cache is being used**. It works if I skip caching and install dependencies every time.

Logs for each step:

*Cache@2*

```
Resolving key:
 - poetry      [string]
 - "Linux"     [string]
 - poetry.lock [file] --> 7AFBEE979DA4396BFE2D0AEF57A0A6A210629F38EFE50786DF26B396ECD935E0
Resolved to: poetry|"Linux"|VHTXv4eVo2iEXIULm/6DKwpSuYJEqaI86WbrPgZ3/T4=
Using default max parallelism.
Max dedup parallelism: 192
Getting a pipeline cache artifact with one of the following fingerprints:
Fingerprint: `poetry|"Linux"|VHTXv4eVo2iEXIULm/6DKwpSuYJEqaI86WbrPgZ3/T4=`
There is a cache hit: `poetry|"Linux"|VHTXv4eVo2iEXIULm/6DKwpSuYJEqaI86WbrPgZ3/T4=`
Used scope: 3012;5b97d788-43ec-45d8-836e-eaa18049b8fb;refs/heads/feature/pipeline-work;ff191ef6-ebfd-4d63-9d61-e7d1f8ceaf65
Entry found at fingerprint: `poetry|"Linux"|VHTXv4eVo2iEXIULm/6DKwpSuYJEqaI86WbrPgZ3/T4=`
Expected size to be downloaded: 121.7 MB
Downloaded 0.0 MB out of 121.7 MB (0%).
Downloaded 121.7 MB out of 121.7 MB (100%).

Download statistics:
Total Content: 121.7 MB
Physical Content Downloaded: 48.8 MB
Compression Saved: 72.9 MB
Local Caching Saved: 0.0 MB
Chunks Downloaded: 1,483
Nodes Downloaded: 3
```

*Show Coverage Installation*

```
 name         : coverage                             
 version      : 6.5.0                                
 description  : Code coverage measurement for Python 

dependencies
 - tomli *
```

*Coverage*

```
poetry run coverage run -m pytest && poetry run coverage xml -o /agent/_work/22/s/TestResults/coverage.xml
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /agent/_work/_temp/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.sh
Command not found: coverage
##[error]Bash exited with code '1'.
Finishing: Run tests & code coverage
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the `$(venv)` for the path value in the cache task, i used `/home/vsts/.virtualenvs` in the sample yaml below. It's working on my side.

```
trigger: none

parameters:
  - name: usePoetryCache
    type: string
    default: true

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
strategy:
  matrix:
    Python36:
      python.version: '3.10'

steps:
- task: UsePythonVersion@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '$(python.version)'
  displayName: 'Use Python $(python.version)'

- script: |
    curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python -
    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=PATH]${PATH}:$HOME/.local/bin"
  displayName: 'Install poetry'


- ${{ if eq(parameters.usePoetryCache, true) }}:
  - task: Cache@2
    inputs:
      key: 'poetry | "$(Agent.OS)"'
      # restoreKeys: |
      #   poetry | "$(Agent.OS)"
      #   poetry
      path: $(venv)
      cacheHitVar: POETRY_CAHCE_RESTORED

- script: |
      poetry config virtualenvs.in-project true
      poetry config virtualenvs.path $(venv)
      poetry lock
  displayName: Configure Poetry

- script: |
    poetry install
  displayName: Install dependencies
  condition: eq(variables.POETRY_CAHCE_RESTORED, 'false')

- script: |
    poetry show coverage
  displayName: Check coverage installation

- script: |
    poetry run coverage run -m pytest
  displayName: Run tests & code coverage
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason you're adding `poetry lock` in the config stage?

Comment: Hi @bitnahian，on my test repo, i added the `coverage` dependency in `pyproject.toml` file which caused poetry.lock is not consistent with pyproject.toml. so i add `poetry lock` to fix it.  Could you please let me know if it's working for you now?